# What is the Big-O Time Complexity of this code?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o-notation, python

I was wondering if someone could please explain what the time complexity is for the code below.

I think it would be $O(n)$ because the algorithm will take as much time to execute as there are elements in $n$.

```py
sample_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]                                          
check_list = []                                                                 
for i in sample_list:                                                           
    if i not in check_list:                                                       
        check_list.append(i)                                                        
    else:
        print(i,end='')
```

Comment: Is anything known about the implementation of `check_list`/`[]`, of `check_list.append()`? What about `i in check_list`?

Answer (score 1):

The code takes $O(n^2)$. It is tricky to see that, since its very easy to miss the fact that `if i not in sample_list` takes another $O(n)$ time - just by itself.

Here is the breakdown of the complexity:

```py
check_list = [] # O(1)
for i in sample_list # repeats n times
    if i not in check_list: # takes an O(n) time to do the check
        check_list.append(i) # takes constant time
    else:
        print(i) # again, constant time
```

Overall, it will take $O(n)$ per call to `if i not in check_list`, which will happen exactly $n$ times - and hence the total complexity is $n\cdot O(n)=O(n^2)$

Comment: Note that $n$ is the size of the input array here. As it stands, the given code just takes constant time.

Comment: I assumed `sample_list` is a general input, and `sample_list=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6]` is just an example. You are right that technically the code as it is right now takes $O(1)$.

Comment: I would have answered like @nirshahar, I would assume the array is not constant, it is just an example to run the code. The question seems to me about the algorithm, not the a specific instance. Any ready to run code can be seen as $O(1)$ if we consider every single array we see in an example a constant...